# Are Jinchūriki immune to Genjutsu?

Tags: naruto

So, everyone knows that Killer Bee instantly broke the Genjustu which Sasuke cast on him. How about other Jinchūriki? We know that Jinchūriki have a lot of chakra because of their Tailed Beasts and they could use this chakra to free themselves from Genjustu.

So, can we say that they are immune to Genjutsu?

Comment: Well!!! No one is immune to genjutsu, not even Jinchuriki. The fact here is that when the Jinchuriki falls for the genjutsu, the sealed bijuu can support the jinchuriki to get away from genjutsu by destabilizing the chakra. Why only Killer Bee was able to cast away a genjutus is that he was known to have built a great bond with Hachibi, so both of them act as a team to overcome genjutsu.

Comment: Edited it. Tell me if there are problems with the edit, if ever it changed the thought of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Jinchuuriki and their tailed beast work together they can basically break every genjutsu put upon them since one of the counters against genjutus is to have the victim's chakra flow disrupted. This makes them mostly immune to them.

> A victim's chakra flow, if disrupted enough, can break the caster's influence. This "Genjutsu Dissipation" (幻術解, Genjutsu Kai, Literally meaning: Illusion Technique Dissipation) or "Genjutsu Reversal" (幻術返し, Genjutsu Gaeshi, Literally meaning: Illusion Technique Reversal)[7] can be done by the victim themselves, (assuming they realise they're under a genjutsu's influence) or an ally who emits chakra into them;[8] jinchūriki who have formed a good relationship with their tailed beast prefer the latter method whenever they need it.

[Wiki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Genjutsu#Countering)

Answer (score 2):

No, Itachi casted a genjutsu on Naruto to keep his kotoamatsukami crow inside naruto. It is just jinchurikis has upper hand than same level ninja as they have more chakra, they can resist more. It is all depends on if the subject is trained enough to resist and if the caster is skilled enough to cast a genjutsu powerful enough to counter the subject.